# Appcelerator Android Push Notifications

Tags: android, push-notification, appcelerator-mobile, titanium-mobile

Does anyone know of a way to implement push notifications using appcelerator for an android device, without using the UrbanAirship module?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Android "push notifications" are called [Cloud to Device Messaging](http://code.google.com/android/c2dm/) (C2DM).

[This blogpost](http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2010/05/android-cloud-to-device-messaging.html) is straight from the development team member.

**Update:**

To use C2DM from Titanium, try the [titanium-c2dm](https://github.com/IGx89/titanium-c2dm) module.

Comment: That blogpost is in Java and the question says "using appcelerator", he can develop an custom module in Java and incorporate it with Appcelerator, but i don't think that is what he is looking for...

Answer (score 0):

[Pusher](http://pusher.com) (who I work for) have an Appcelerator Titanium module for Android and iPhone. You should contact support@pusher.com if you are interested.

*Note: Clearly this doesn't use UrbanAirship, but I'm not 100% sure if you actually mean you want to remove all private 3rd party dependencies*

Answer (score 0):

Using Appcelerator Cloud Service(ACS) you can implement the Push Notification.

It is the simplest and reliable one. Follow the below tutorial for ACS Push Notification implementation on Android

http://www.titaniumtutorial.com/2012/06/appcelerator-cloud-push-notification-in.html

Hope it helps someone